# How can i make an array have the keys and values from a string in another array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that goes like this:

```
0 => '"number1":1', 
1 => '"number2":2', 
2 => '"number3":3',
```

...etc

Now i want to make a new array that will have number1 as key and 1 as value, so it'll look like this:

```
"number1" => 1, 
"number2" => 2, 
"number3" => 3,
```

...etc

How can i do this?

Comment: array_map, explode, array_combine, array_column, https://3v4l.org/XAv7b or just bog-standard loop over it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

foreach main array, and explode() each value within and place everything in a new array.

Edit:

```
<?php
$newArray = array();
$oldArray = array(0=>'"number1":1'...);

foreach($oldArray as $old){
    $item = explode(':',$old);
    $newArray[$item[0]] = $item[1];
}
?>
```

Comment: You need to trim away the `"` around the string `number` as well. You can do it like this: `$newArray[trim($item[0], '"')]`